# Why can't gate not be found

Tags: omnet++

When ever I try to run my simulation I get the message

> sendDelayed(): No such gate or gate vector: 'rdrsucess1' -- in module (rdr) radr.rdrchk1 (id=2), during network initialization

Here is my NED code:

```
simple rdr
{
    gates:
        input in[];
        output out[];
}

//

network radr
{
    @display("bgb=356,232");
    submodules:
        rdrchk1: rdr {
            @display("p=49,41");
        }
        rdrfail1: rdr {
            @display("p=207,146");
        }
        rdrsucess1: rdr {
            @display("p=207,48");
        }
    connections:
        rdrchk1.out++ --> {   } --> rdrfail1.in++;
        
        rdrchk1.out++ --> {   } --> rdrsucess1.in++;
        
}
```

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;


class rdr : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;


};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(rdr);

void rdr::initialize()
{
    int v1 = rand() % 100;
        int v2 = rand() % 100;
        int v3 = rand() % 100;
    if (strcmp("rdrchk1", getName()) == 0) {
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("objectcheck");


     if (v1<78|| v2 < 82 || v3 <69){
                 send(msg, "rdrsucess1");

     }
     else{
         send(msg, "rdrfail1");

     }
    }

}

void rdr::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{

    send(msg, "out");
}
```

Here is my INI code:

```
[General]
network = radr
 record-eventlog = true
```

I just need to know how to change "send(msg, "rdrsucess1");" so that I can send a msg to rdrsucess1 from rdrcheck1. This information should alow me to also fix rdrfail1. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no gate `rdrsucess1` in simple module `rdr`. That module has an output gate named `out`. Moreover, note that gate `out` is a vector gate. Therefore you should send a message using something like that:

```
int n = ....  // index of particular output gate
send(msg, "out", n);
```

Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:sending-messages)

Comment: How do you determine index of gate?

Comment: You use `++` operator for definition of connections, so OMNeT++ takes index 0 of gate `out` in `rdrchk1` to create connection to `rdrfail1` and index 1 for connection to `rdrsucess1`. In other words: the order of entries in `connections` determines the assignment of indexes. Another solution is to: 1) set the size of gate `out` to 2 (i.e. `output out[2];` 2) intentionally use indexes during definition of connection, for example `rdrchk1.out[0] --> {   } --> rdrfail1.in++;` That way index becomes independent of order of entries.